# "Околораневая" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно написать: околораневая или около раневая поверхность?

Answer (score 1):

Пишется слитно: **околораневая поверхность.**

*Около* может быть либо предлогом, либо приставкой.

*Около* как предлог требует родительного падежа (около чего?).
*Около* как приставка пишется слитно – это наш случай.

(См http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE&all=x)

Например: **околораневая**, или паратравматическая, экзема ([Заболевания кожи](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=WY6gAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT397&lpg=PT397&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F,%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=ZlWMT7JSo8&sig=6QUFhRgTSGANN867whfptm66lUc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTkYnogonXAhXJyRoKHfodANsQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%22&f=false))